# How does the library dependency is inherited/works in maven?

Tags: java, scala, maven, gradle

I have gradle scala project(Lets say **"A"**) which uses the library(Lets say **"X"**). And i have used this **Library-"X"** in the build.gradle of **Project-A** as shown below and i'm using the **Library-X** classes to perform some operations.

build.gradle of **Project-"A"**

```
implementation "com.x.y.z.stone:central-dl-spark-common-integration-logging:0.4.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Now **Project-"A"** is itself a library which is used in the **Project-"B"** and this **Project-B** is maven build. Now when i call the **Project-A** function which is acting as library in-turn uses **Library-X** function. But **Project-B** is complaining that class not found error as shown below. This is the **Library-X** class

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/x/y/z/integrationlogging/IntegrationLogging$
```

My question is do we even need to declare the **Library-X** in the pom.xml of **Project-B** as well?

Answer (score 0):

No: if Project-B imports Project-A, and Project-A has an internal dependency on Library-X, you usually don't need to do anything and it will resolve automatically.

Some exceptions may include conflicts and libraries that exist in a private nexus. For the former, you need to resolve the conflict in the pom.xml. For the latter, you need to make sure your repo is accessible from wherever you're compiling.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Dependencies are transitive "by default" unless the opposite is specificied (either with *exclusions* or *scopes* (a test scoped dependency won't be transitively propagated for instance)).

EDIT: you can use `mvn dependency:tree` to get a better understanding of your dependencies.

One possibility is that library X is pulled in different incompatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the having look at my post. By adding the Library-X under  tag in the Project-B pom.xml, worked.Something shown below

```
<artifactSet>                           
<include>x.y.stone:central-dl-spark-common-integration-logging</include>
</artifactSet>
```